# Usage of the noun suffix "-ment"

Tags: verbs, nouns, suffixes, morphology, productive-affixes

What is a good rule for the usage of the noun suffix *-ment*?
Is *desirement* as acceptable as *achievement*?

Comment: *Desire* is already a noun as well as a verb. There's no need to make the noun *desire* into a longer noun by adding *-ment*, and in fact *desirement* is not a word. Since *achieve* is not already a noun, it makes sense to turn it into a noun by adding *-ment*.

Comment: Read is a verb but not (normally) a noun, and readment doesn't exist. Neither do snorement and takement. You need to look up individual cases in a good dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

-ment is not a free suffix you can add as you like. The nouns ending in -ment are 
either Latin or French. And the etymology of -ment is not clear. Even the meaning of -men and -mentum is difficult to analysize. If you study the Latin nouns in -men/mentum you find that the nouns are of various types and it is not possible to give a simple idea of the formation of these words. I could give my private view, but that would take too long and I think it would hardly help you.

Comment: [This  U. Mass. source](http://people.umass.edu/aimm/abstracts/Modeling%20Emergent%20Productivity%20of%20Rival%20Suffixes.pdf) says that the suffix -ment was/is productive, though increasingly less so: "Of course, not all suffixes 
succeed in adapting; formerly productive suffix -ment began a gradual decline in productivity in 
the 17th century because five times as many competing -ation words were being borrowed into 
English during that century. Since -ment failed to associate itself with any meaningful subset of 
potential hosts, it lost out to -ation."

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth  Interesting comment and thanks for the link. I wanted to dissuade the poster from forming his own words with -ment.

Comment: Your answer may mean the U. Mass. article is using 'productive' in an unusual way; the -ation words may well be largely French imports, so increasing the English lexicon with loan-words rather than by domestic suffixation. I couldn't agree more about the unacceptableness of making one's own -ment words up, though. What confusement would result!

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth  Well, I doubt that -ment is a productive suffix in normal language. But in the divers sciences there may well be new formations with -ment for new things. So I took the comment as it was. By the way, what are "hosts" of subsets? I'm not used to explanations of language with terms of the set theory.

Comment: I've no idea. But a subset of potential hosts might have been {verbs ending in -ine and needing a related noun} = {examine, determine, predestine ...}, which -ation rather than -ment snaffled (a technical term).